# Create dynamic changing ProgressMonitor

Tags: java, progress-bar, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to create ProgressMonitor with changing totalWork.
Lets assume that I have 2 steps. The first step is retrieving a list of objects. The totalWork=-1 (UNKNOWN).

In the second step I change every object from the lisl. So I want to change totalWork to the size of the list. I've tried something like the code below, but it didn't work:

```
int totalWork = -1
monitor.beginTask("Task", totalWork);
monitor.subTask("Start Subtask 1");
final List<Object> list = retrieveList();
totalWork = list.size();
monitor.subTask("Retrieve Events");
for(Object obj:list){
   //do some job
   monitor.worked(1)
}
monitor.done()
```

Is there a way to achieve that ?

**EDIT:** I'm extending Job and the code above is in the run method.

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fdialogs%2FProgressMonitorDialog.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No!

Longer answer:

If the first step takes less than 100ms (even for very large data sets), then this is usually done before `beginTask`...

In many cases will the initial count operation take an amount of time that is very much comparable to the actual operation. And in this case you can use an embedded `SubProgressMonitor`. Lets say the initial count takes 1/20 of the later operation:

```
public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
    monitor.beginTask("Task", 1+20);
    try {
        monitor.subTask("Initializing");
        final List<Object> list = retrieveList();
        monitor.worked(1);

        IProgressMonitor sub = new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, 20);
        sub.beginTask("", list.size());
        for (Object o : list) {
            sub.subTask(""+o);
            // ...
            sub.worked(1);
        }
        sub.done();
    } finally {
        monitor.done();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well the problem is that I don't really know how long would it take(reading information from database), but is more than a 2-3 seconds. The second step is taking alot more and that's why I need to show the progress. I've found another solution: I run 2 times monitor.beginTask. The first time by reading the objects from database with -1 totalWork(Unknown) and the second time with totalWork = the size of the list.

Comment: Don't call `beginTask(...)` multiple times for the same progress monitor.... there are several implementations that will fail on that. See http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Progress-Monitors/article.html for more information...

Comment: Where can I get the `IProgressMonitor` library/jar/etc ?

Comment: `IProgressMonitor` is part of the Equinox core runtime. Check out the Eclipse plug-in API.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution to my problem.

```
int totalWork = -1
monitor.beginTask("Task 1", totalWork);
monitor.subTask("Start Subtask 1");
final List<Object> list = retrieveList();
totalWork = list.size();
monitor.beginTask("Retrieve Events",totalWork);
for(Object obj:list){
   //do some job
   monitor.worked(1)
}
monitor.done()
```